# awk find the last match and print the next N lines

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have a log file which contains the following content:

```
Date: 2014-09-07
Price: 1.35
Amount: 20
ProcessedBy: Bill

Some other contents

Date: 2014-09-08
Price: 10.1
Amount: 15
ProcessedBy: Alice

Some other contents

Date: 2014-09-09
Price: 100
Amount: 2.6
ProcessedBy: Boss

Some other contents
```

I would like to use awk to find the last "Date", and print the following three lines.

```
Date: 2014-09-09
Price: 100
Amount: 2.6
ProcessedBy: Boss
```

I use the code:

`awk '/Date/ {x=NR}; END{NR>=x && NR<=x+3} LOG_FILE`

However, it seems that I cannot put NR output after END.

How can I get the following N lines after the last match?

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk  '/^Date:/ {c=1; a=$0;next} c<=3{c=c+1;a=a"\n"$0}END{print a}' LOG_FILE
Date: 2014-09-09
Price: 100
Amount: 2.6
ProcessedBy: Boss
```

Taking the code one piece at a time:

- `/^Date:/ {c=1; a=$0;next}`

  Every time that a line starting with `Date:` is encountered, assign counter `c` to one, assign the line to the variable `a`, and skip to the next line
- `c<=3{c=c+1;a=a"\n"$0}`

  If the counter is less than or equal to three, increment the counter and save the new line to the end of variable `a`.
- `END{print a}`

  Print the last-seen value of `a`.

#### Code for the second version of this question

```
$ awk -v RS=  '/^Date:/ {a=$0} END{print a}' LOG_FILE
Date: 2014-09-09
Price: 100
Amount: 2.6
ProcessedBy: Boss
```

Taking the code one piece at a time:

- `-v RS=`

  `awk` divides its input up into "records."  This works by setting the record separator `RS` to a blank line.  (For GNU `awk`, an empty `RS` matches an empty line.  For other versions of `awk`, you may need to do something different.)
- `/^Date:/ {a=$0}`

  Every time a record is encountered that starts with `Date:`, it is saved in the variable `a`.
- `END{print a}`

  At the end of the run, the last-seen value of `a` is printed.

#### Code for first version of this question

```
$ awk -v RS=  'END{print $0}' LOG_FILE
Date: 2014-09-09
Price: 100
Amount: 2.6
ProcessedBy: Boss
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation! Using RS= is a good option, but actually my log file contains some other contents which may not be relevant to current data extraction (previously I didn't describe it clearly, sorry). I would like to find the last occurrence of "Date", and print the next three lines. But the way I used to find the last "Date" and use "END" to print does not work. Could you suggest how I can achieve this?

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation and multiple answers!

Answer (score 1):

You could try perl also,

```
$ perl -0777pe 's/.*?\n(Date:(?:(?!Date:).)*)$/\1/s' file
Date: 2014-09-09
Price: 100
Amount: 2.6
ProcessedBy: Boss
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -v RS= '/^Date:/{data=$0} END{print data}' file
Date: 2014-09-09
Price: 100
Amount: 2.6
ProcessedBy: Boss
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try just print lines between two pattern as follow

```
awk '/StartPattern/,/EndPattern/' FileName
```

for you it can work like this

```
awk '/2014-09-09/,/ProcessedBy/' FileName
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. sometimes I do not know exactly what the pattern is (e.g. what date is recorded in the log), therefore I have to find the last occurrence :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not put `NR` in `END`, but you can do like this:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} /^Date/ {f=NR} END {for (i=f;i<f+4;i++) print a[i]}'
Date: 2014-09-09
Price: 100
Amount: 2.6
ProcessedBy: Boss
```

It store all line in array `a`, then  store last `Date` in `f`.
In `END` block, print from array `a` four lines after hit of last  `Date`