# awk to print from last match of start match pattern till end pattern

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file with contents like this.

```
if {[CELL NAME "CELL1"]} {
define_cell \
       -pinlist { i0 i1 i2 0 } \
       CELL1
}
if {[CELL NAME "CELL2"]} {
define_cell \
       -pinlist { i0 i1 i2 0 } \
       CELL2
}
define_cell \
       -pinlist { i0 i1 i2 0 } \
       CELL3  
define_cell \
       -pinlist { i0 i1 i2 0 } \
       CELL4
```

I am trying to get a subsection like this.

```
define_cell \
       -pinlist { i0 i1 i2 0 } \
       CELL3
```

When I am trying to do so with a simple script like below, I am actually getting from first match of define_cell till the end of the file contrary to my expectation.

```
awk '/define_cell/,/CELL3/{print $0}' <FILE>
```

How can I achieve the specific goal. I have tried to follow the solutions suggested in this.
[awk find the last match and print the next N lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738205/awk-find-the-last-match-and-print-the-next-n-lines)
But not able to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk something like this might work:

```
awk '{$0=RT$0}/CELL3/' ORS= RS=define_cell input.txt
```

The above will split records on `define_cell` and then print records containing `CELL3`.

Alternative you can use the following which will store each line to print in `r` and delete it every time `define_cell` is matched:

```
awk '/define_cell/ { l=1; delete r}
                 l { r[l++]=$0 }
           /CELL3/ { for(i=1;i<l;i++) print r[i] }' input.txt
```

You can also used `tac` to read the file from behind:

```
tac input.txt | awk '/CELL3/,/define_cell/' | tac
```

Comment: There is a problem when the first solution is used for CELL4 (last one in the list). The define_cell line goes missing!
Any clues how that can be fixed?
`bash-4.2$ awk '{$0=RT$0}/CELL4/' ORS= RS=define_cell /tmp/input.txt
 \
       -pinlist { i0 i1 i2 0 } \
       CELL4`

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer with `grep`:

```
grep -A 2 "^define_cell" input.txt | grep -B 2 "CELL3"
```

With `-A 2` to extract two lines after the first match, and with `-B 2` to extract the two lines before the last match, that is how you get both match.